# Shell script using --eval printing unintended values to output

Tags: javascript, mongodb, shell, eval

I am trying to pass to variables from a shell script to a mongo (javascript) script while kicking it off. Everything I read said you can pass these variables using --eval in your command line. This worked great, but the output always prints my second --eval variable printed out...

**Shell Script**

```
#!/bin/bash
foo = "10"
mongo --quiet --eval "start = '$foo'" mongoScript.js
```

**Output**

```
10
ID,Time,Local
035435406354,13:01:01,MST
035435406354,13:01:01,MST
```

The problem is that eval now returns a value so this gets printed to my output. How do I suppress this?

Comment: What does this have to do with `bash`?

Answer (score 0):

After enough searching on the web, I was able to find that if I declare the variable inside the --eval (var), it will not print the value of the variable in the output.

**Solution**

```
#!/bin/bash
foo = "10"
mongo --quiet --eval "var start = '$foo'" mongoScript.js
```

This gives me the expected output without displaying an extra line with the value of start

**Output**

```
ID,Time,Local
035435406354,13:01:01,MST
035435406354,13:01:01,MST
```